# delay на смену заголовка

Tags: javascript

Пожалуй, это глупый вопрос, но почему-то не получается разобраться.
Есть такая интересная маленькая и хрупкая библиотека i miss you: https://github.com/Bahlaouane-Hamza/I-Miss-You (github). Суть в том, что когда мы уходим со вкладки, заголовок меняется на какой мы захотим, например, на i miss you, а так же можно поменять иконку до тех пор, пока пользователь не вернеться.

Нахожу навязчивым ставить такое в обычный режим, поэтому хотел бы сделать delay хотя бы в 30 минут, но не получается это сделать таким образом, каким умею я.

> ```
> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script src="jquery.iMissYou.js"></script>
> <script>
>     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
>         $.iMissYou({
>             title: "I Miss you !",
>             favicon: {
>                 enabled: true,
>                 src:'iMissYouFavicon.ico'
>             }
>         });
>     });
> </script>
> ```

Спасите неваляшку! Умоляю!

Comment: Судя по тому, что к этому плагину нет никакой документации, в нём нет возможность сделать то, что вы хотите. Единственный выход - открыть исходных код плагина и переписать его.

Comment: А поставить какой-нибудь delay на $.iMissYou невозможно?

Comment: Нет, ведь слушатель на смену вкладки навешивается внутри  `$.iMissYou();`

Comment: Извините, Анатолий, а вы не знаете, нет ли какой-то альтернативы сделать то же самое что и тут, но собственными руками или с помощью другой библиотеки?

Comment: дополнил ответ примером

Comment: сейчас приведу более полный пример

Comment: Спасибо, понял. А как с фавиконом такое же реализовать Вы не знаете? Извините, что утруждаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по тому, что к этому плагину нет никакой документации, в нём нет возможность сделать то, что вы хотите. Единственный выход - открыть исходных код плагина и переписать его.

Поставить задержку на  `$.iMissYou();` не выйдет, т.к. слушатель на смену вкладки навешивается самим плагином...

Можно попробовать обойтись без плагина, смену тайтла можно сделать как-то так :

```
<script>
    window.onblur = function () {document.title='документ неактивен'}
    window.onfocus = function () {document.title='документ снова активен'}
</script>
```

А если с задержкой, то как-то так:

```
timerId = null;

function func1() {
   document.title='документ неактивен'
}

function func2() {
    document.title='документ снова активен'
}


window.onblur = function () {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(func1, 30000);
}
window.onfocus = function () {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    func2();
}
```

Сменить фавикон можно как-то так (не уверен что сработает, сам не пробовал):

```
<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icon1.png" />

$("#favicon").attr("href","icon2.png");
```

Фавиконки обычно жестко кешируются, нужно пробовать...

Comment: Понял, а как фавиконку поменять?

Comment: сейчас приведу пример

Comment: а, ещё перед тем, как делать задержку нужно сбрасывать timeout

Comment: Спасибо большое!) Вы меня прям спасли. Я крайне благодарен, правда!

Comment: В этом случае нужно?

Comment: Исправил, таймер устанавливается только на `blur`, таймаут очищается перед установкой нового таймера, он предварительно присваивается переменной, которая должна быть доступна в функции, можно сделать её глобальной. Ну если уж очень помог, то можно и стрелочку вверх нажать ;)

Comment: Понял! Записал, сохранил. Буду смотреть. Для фавиконки всё так же делаю, верно?

Comment: Я только зарегистрировался, пишет нужно 15 баллов набрать. Уже хотел "стрелочку вверх нажать". Как только наберу - сразу зайду сюда и нажму, я даже вкладку сохранил. Договорились?

Comment: могут возникнуть проблемы, если вы перейдете на другую вкладку и тут же вернётесь, тайтл сменится, когда вкладка уже будет активна, clearTimeout наверное нужно поместить и во второй слушатель